# Error loading RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp

I successfully installed RcppArmadillo by typing:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/src/GCC/install/gcc-4.8.2/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
wget https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.18.tar.gz
wget https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.8.600.0.0.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.12.18.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL RcppArmadillo_0.8.600.0.0.tar.gz
```

However, when I try to load RcppArmadillo, I have the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppArmadillo’ in 
dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/home/ecg/ad603/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu- 
library/3.5/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by 
/home/ecg/ad603/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You probably need the same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings for the R session as you used for the compilation.

Comment: It works ok in command-line R, but not in Rstudio. I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside Rstudio, but it still fails with the same error.

Comment: You have to set it _before_ you launch RStudio.

Comment: I did, I added in the .Renviron file ```PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/src/GCC/install/gcc-4.8.2/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib``` and obviously restarted Rstudio but the error persist

Comment: Try `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` ie by adding a `local-gcc.conf` there. What you did may help with R alone but as you launch RStudio to run and start R so you need it before RStudio starts.